# Errors Creating A Shared Library DLL for SWIG Simple Lua Example (Windows 7)

Tags: c, gcc, lua, mingw, swig

I use MinGW to create, and my lua version is 5.1.4 the followings are my steps:

```
swig -lua  example.i
gcc -c example_wrap.c -I C:\Lua\5.1\include
gcc -c example.c -I C:\Lua\5.1\include
gcc -shared example_wrap.o example.o -o  example.dll
```

errors ocurrs at last step, here are some part of the errors information

```
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2aef): undefined reference to `lua_gettop'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2afe): undefined reference to `lua_gettop'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2b2d): undefined reference to `lua_pushfstring'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2b38): undefined reference to `lua_error'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2b67): undefined reference to `lua_pushnumber'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2ec0): undefined reference to `lua_pushvalue'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2ee3): undefined reference to `lua_pushstring'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2efe): undefined reference to `lua_pushcclosure'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2f11): undefined reference to `lua_rawset'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2f24): undefined reference to `lua_pushstring'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2f3f): undefined reference to `lua_pushcclosure'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x2f52): undefined reference to `lua_rawset'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

it seems that I didn't include the lua header?
so I also try these commands but no use

```
gcc -shared example_wrap.o example.o  -I C:\Lua\5.1\include -o  example.dll
```

so any suggestions?

Comment: try including `lua51.dll` when you link

Comment: do you mean this? same errors.
gcc -shared example_wrap.o -I C:\Lua\5.1\lib\ -o example.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to link with this command:

```
gcc -LC:\Lua\5.1\bin -shared example_wrap.o example.o -llua51 -o example.dll
```

the path in the `-LC:\Lua\5.1\bin` part should point to the directory where you have your `lua51.dll` (I assumed `bin`, as in my system, but change it to suit your installation).